# Python keyerror even though dictionary key exists

Tags: python

The below caused a key error when trying to access ret_dict['mesh_triangles_center']:

```
    mtc_arr = []
    mfn_arr = []
    ...
    ret_dict['mesh_triangles_center'] = np.stack(mtc_arr, axis=0)
    ret_dict['mesh_face_normals'] = np.stack(mfn_arr, axis=0)
```

I'm not sure why. It seems might have something to do with the original mtc_arr mutability.

Answer (score 0):

Using deepcopy fixed it:

```
    ret_dict['mesh_triangles_center'] = copy.deepcopy(np.stack(mtc_arr, axis=0))
    ret_dict['mesh_face_normals'] = copy.deepcopy(np.stack(mfn_arr, axis=0))
```